# how to add more than one sign header to domain emails in opendkim

Tags: dkim, domainkeys

I have running opendkim in a server.
In this server I have two domains:

- the main
- my gateway for outgoing emails

Now in my signing table I add by each domain a sign `DKIM`.

I want to know if its possible add two signs to secondary domain.

I want this because when our server use ip of main domain, and `MAILGUN` do the same, add DKIM sign of `mailgun.org` and add `DKIM` sign to `yourdomain.org`, I too want to add main domain's `DKIM` signature and secondary domain's `DKIM` signature to emails of secondary domain, for arrive to received folder in gmail and not in spam folder.

Best regards.

Comment: Its Exactly that I am  looking up

Answer (score 2):

I found solution, you must edit /etc/opendkim.conf and add MultipleSignatures      Yes, next is edit /etc/opendkim/SigingTable
*@primary.com mail._domainkey.primary.com
*@secondary.net mail._domainkey.secondary.net

and add
*@secondary.net mail._domainkey.primary.com

That is all :)